# javascript - how to NOT assign by reference

Tags: javascript, reference

Okay consider this bit of code:

```
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = d1;

d2.setDate(d2.getDate()+1);
alert(d1 + "\n" + d2);
```

Even though I call `setDate()` on `d2`, `d1` is also being incremented.  I understand this to be because d1 is assigned to `d2` by reference.  My question is...how do I NOT do this, so that `.setDate()` only gets applied to `d2`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In JavaScript, [all objects are assigned to variables 'by reference'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9070366/201952).  You need to create a copy of the object; `Date` makes it easy:

```
var d2 = new Date(d1);
```

This will create a new date object copying `d1`'s value.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
var d2 = new Date(d1.getTime());
```

See [How to clone a Date object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090815/how-to-clone-a-date-object-in-javascript) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Think this should work:

```
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date();
d2.setDate(d1.getDate());

d2.setDate(d2.getDate()+1);
alert(d1 + "\n" + d2);
```