# How to add a external element date block of 3 days with drag n' drop with fullcalender

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I am using the http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ to create a simple calender with a drag and drop functionality, and I was hoping if anyone who has had experience using it can helping me out a bit with a question I'm having.

What I am trying to achieve is to create a draggable block that highlights a set of days instead of one day in the calender. My approch to solving this was to take the day I drop the block and count the next 3 days and set that as my end date.

```
        //create 3 day block
        var threeDayBlock= date;
        threeDayBlock.setDate(threeDayBlock.getDate() + 2);
```

Then add it to the calender as follows

```
        copiedEventObject.end = threeDayBlock;
```

What this does however is, once I drop it to a selected date it moves the event 3 days ahead instead. What I would like it to do instead is enter a three day block from the day I drop it to 3 days ahead.

Here is my code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rayshinn/ZTWgD/3/

I really appreciate any help I can get to solving this matter! Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that you're creating a *reference* called `threeDayBlock` to the object `date`.  Therefore, when you change `threeDayBlock`, you're changing `date` as well.  All you need to do is copy the `date` object instead of referencing it:

```
var threeDayBlock = new Date(date.getTime());
```

That's it!

See it working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/ZTWgD/4/

Also, to understand how Javascript deals with values being copied vs referenced, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069120/are-there-any-rules-of-thumb-for-when-javascript-values-are-copied-by-reference/9070366#9070366).

Comment: that makes perfect sense! Thank you so much!